# Incorrect assign symbol to char or string

Tags: c++

```
A="D:\Kursa4\a1\a1\test1.txt";
B="D:\Kursa4\a1\a1\test1.txt";
```

```
+       A   "D:Kursa411 est1.txt"   std::basic_string,std::allocator >

+       B   0x0046cd0c "D:Kursa411  est1.txt"   char *
```

'\' symbol uncorected when I assign it to char or string. I need to replace '\' to '/' - but when I write '\' - indicates text below

I'm read name of file in this format. And want to replace \ to /

```
ZeroMemory(&of, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));
    of.lStructSize = sizeof( OPENFILENAME );
    of.Flags = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST| OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ENABLESIZING; 
    of.lCustData = (DWORD) NULL;
    //of.hwndOwner = hWnd; 
    of.lpstrFilter = L"*.*";
    of.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)fsFile;
    of.nMaxFile = sizeof(fsFile);
    of.nFilterIndex = 1;
    of.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
    of.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
    if(GetOpenFileName(&of) == TRUE)
    {
    //IDC_EDIT1
    //HWND hwndEdit1 = GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_RADIO1);
    SetWindowText(hwndEdit1, (LPCWSTR)fsFile);
    }
```

**I want make "D:\Kursa4\a1\a1\test1.txt" from "D:/Kursa4/a1/a1/test.txt"**

```
char B = "D:/Kursa4/a1/a1/test.txt";
```

Home make ?

```
 char B = "D:\Kursa4\a1\a1\test1.txt";
```

Comment: @abelenky, the bottom code given is indeed C++, but it's the Windows API.

Comment: @chris: The bottom code was not present when I commented.

Comment: @abelenky, Oh, that makes a bit more sense. That's not a lot to go on.

Comment: I want make "D:\Kursa4\a1\a1\test1.txt" from "D:/Kursa4/a1/a1/test.txt"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
A="D:\\Kursa4\\a1\\a1\\test1.txt";
B="D:\\Kursa4\\a1\\a1\\test1.txt";
```

In C++ source code, the `\` symbol modifies the meaning of the next symbol in the string. `\t`, for example means "horizontal-tab", while `\n` means "new-line".

In order to insert an actual `\` character, you must type `\\`.

Comment: I'm read name of file in this format...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to understand, but from what I see you did not escape your backslashes.

Use

```
A="D:\\Kursa4\\a1\\a1\\test1.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (and in C), in string and character literals, the backslash is an
"escape character"; that means that it doesn't represent itself, but
signals that what follows (usually the next character, but sometimes
more) has a special meaning.  Thus. from your strings, the two character
sequence `"\a"` in a string or character literal means a character which
generates an audible alarm, the BEL character (0x07 in most encodings).
And of course, you've almost certainly seen `"\n"` for a new line
character, and the `"\""` for a quote character; `"\t"` for a tab
character is also quite frequent.

This creates the problem: how do you insert a backslash in a string
literal.  The answer is: the same way we insert other characters which
can't be specified directly: with an escape sequence.  In this case,
`"\\"`.

Finally: your text looks like a Windows filename.  In which case, you're
probably better off using `'/'` as the directory separator; if nothing
else, it's a lot easier to type, and to read, as you don't need to use
an escape sequence.  For display purposes, if you're worried about
confusing a non-programming user (who may not know that both `/` and `\`
work under Windows), a quick pass with `std::replace` will fix up the
display string.